# objective c (ipad) dismissViewControllerAnimated not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a splitviewcontroller that would call a loginview controller if there's a need for a login. This is how I would call the modal view

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"] == nil){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:self];
    }
```

This is how my storyboard looks like:

```
                                    --- uinavigation
                       - masterview |
uispliviewcontroller
                       - detailview |
                                    --- main dashboard view -(LoginSegue)--loginviewcontroller
                                             |
                                             |------ another viewcontroller
```

now I can get to the loginview without a problem and then I would try to dismiss the modal so it can go back to the maindashboard view using this

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"] != nil){

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

but it wouldn't do anything.

Was wondering how I can properly dismiss that modal view that was called after login?

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What version of iOS? Have you confirmed that the if statement is evaluating to true and being executed?

Comment: 6. Hmm. Not really sure how to confirm.

Comment: Add an NSLog to the conditional statement to see that it gets there in the first place.

Comment: oh you mean where it checks for the username? yeah it goes through there. I stepped through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a login, a modal presentation might make more sense.  Rather than connecting it with a segue, give the LoginViewController a Storyboard ID, like "LoginViewController". (delete the segue to it, select the login vc in storyboard and find the storyboard id field in the identity inspector).

Then, instead of `performSegue`, do this ...

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Having done this, the dismiss will function as you expect it to.

Comment: let me try this real quick. btw, i'm trying to understand how that "completion" part works. it seems like you can attach stuff to it? like this >> http://stackoverflow.com/a/8021808/639713 I'm not sure why they add those lines to it. Any chance you can explain that for a bit?

Comment: also, @Joel is correct, none of this works if the dismiss doesn't get run.  You can confirm by putting NSLog(@"about to dismiss"); inside that condition.

Comment: yeah i already have that checked and the code goes through there. oh and that thing you recommended worked. just wondering though, is it more efficient (or better practice) to do it that way (no segue and uses storyboard id) or with a segue? Is that the only way to handle logins for splitviews?

Comment: you know, the suggestion was just what my apps do for login type interaction.  let me do some research about whether segue can be used in this case (and if not, why not).  will post here if i learn anything.